# Xcode Storyboard Warning not providing context: Unsupported Configuration of constraint attributes

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard, compiler-warnings

I have this warning, which does not appear to cause any issues when running, but it has been the only warning I have for a while now, and I'd like to see it gone.

[image]

Clicking it opens the storyboard, but nothing is selected in the view hierarchy nor on the storyboard. Right clicking and clicking "view in log" does nothing. Right clicking and selecting "Open As > Source Code" crashes XCode every time.  Right clicking the storyboard from the project navigator and opening as source code does not show any warning information near the top, as other storyboard warnings I have encountered did.

I can not find any information on this warning on SO or Apple documentation. I can find other "Unsupported Configuration" warnings, but none with this type of message.

Any idea how I can find the source of and resolve this warning?

Thanks

Edit - My particular issue is a bug on Apple's part, dealing with web views, and there is no way around it.  It is mis-categorizing a warning. If you've got this error with similar results while trying to source it as I have, you may be running into the same issue: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/63254

However, JOM's answer is incredibly helpful for fixing what seems to be the actual intended occurrence of this warning, as well as very helpful for tracking similar issues. Seeing as how it provides the proper way of resolving this warning, and people are more likely to find this question by running into the warning and not experiencing the same issue as me, I'll mark it as correct.

And for better SEO, the warning is: "Unsupported configuration of constraint attributes. This may produce unexpected results at runtime before Xcode 5.1"

Comment: you need to find out one or more constraint which will look faded in your storyboard. this happens when you are using size class and you deleted one or more `element` but the `constraint` still exists for that. try once.

Comment: How certain are you that that is the case? I saw another "Unsupported Configuration" warning, but the description was different, and more similar to what you are saying. I forget the exact wording, but it basically said an object was missing. I don't exactly have a tiny storyboard, and it would take me about an hour to expand every single element in all my VCs to check each constraint object. I don't want to waste that hour without being sure.

Comment: Well nobody want to waste that much time. I think we can find out any way to identify that specific constraint. I need to check once. we have to reproduce this situation forcefully in a blank storyboard and then we need to check in the source code view of storyboard that this constraint block has any different syntax then the normal ones. if it contains a slight different syntax, even a character. then we just have to match that pattern and search in your huge storyboard. am on it.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Open build log and check the warning by expanding the details by tapping the small box icon at right side of the warning. You should find something like this at the end:

> /* com.apple.ibtool.document.warnings */
>   /Users/username/git/folder/project/Collection/Collection.storyboard:2f5-sJ-euT:
>   warning: Unsupported configuration of constraint attributes. This may
>   produce unexpected results at runtime before Xcode 5.1

Now open that storyboard as Source Code and search for the ID mentioned in warning. In this case it's `2f5-sJ-euT`. You should find something like this:

```
<constraint firstAttribute="centerX" secondItem="ReE-6A-euY"
    secondAttribute="centerX" id="2f5-sJ-euT"/>
```

Now you can check what's the problem. To help that you could e.g. check where is this constraint by looking at possible `reuseIdentifier` of the containing object. Makes it easier to find it, when you open the storyboard in Storyboard format.

In my case the warning was about a constraint that wasn't needed any more and I just removed it. And tested that the app still worked like it was supposed to, of course.

Comment: I believe had that been the particular issue, it would have had the proper segue highlighted on the storyboard, as I've seen in the past. 

However, following your advice I was able to get more info than was available in the issue navigator, seeing that the issue is "Class PLBuildVersion is implemented in both....", coming from two Apple controlled classes. Googling that more specific warning, I was able to find this: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/63254  Apparently there is nothing I can do about it but report to Apple.

Comment: Since your answer led me to the correct answer, if you change your answer to be more generic to get more info on this warning, as that was a significant part of my problem, I'll mark your answer as correct. As it stands, I don't want to mark it as correct since it was not the answer to the issue and I hate when an incorrect answer is selected, but I want to give you your points.

Comment: It's ok, no problem! My answer is specific to constraint, since that's the only thing mentioned in your question. Also this kind of constraint issues are hard to figure out, I had the same warning. Thanx to your question, I realized I should check storyboard as source code :)

Comment: The warning mentioned constraints, but it seems to be something about including a UIWebview on the storyboard that triggers the warning, and the constraint mentioning is just a mis-categorized warning on Apple's part.

Comment: @JakeT. I currently have the warning in a project and there is no web view on the storyboard, so either that's not the culprit or there are multiple ways of triggering the warning

Comment: My specific issue was definitely tied to the webview, but it's a bug on Apple's part misclassifying the warning.  Perhaps they have misclassified other warnings as well. I did mention how this answer helped me determine my actual problem.

Comment: You can remove unwanted constraint.

Answer (score 0):

I'm just clean project and problem gone (cmd+k)